# boost::filesystem::create_directories(".") fails

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem, working-directory

`boost::filesystem::create_directories(".")` always fails on my system.  It seems like this might be a bug, but after reading the documentation I'm not entirely sure.  Here's an example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
try
{
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    std::cerr << "is_directory: " << fs::is_directory(argv[1]) << '\n';
    std::cerr << "create_directory: " << fs::create_directory(argv[1]) << '\n';
    std::cerr << "create_directories: " << fs::create_directories(argv[1]) << '\n';
}
catch (const std::exception& ex)
{
    std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
}
```

If I run this with the argument `.` (meaning the current directory), it prints:

```
is_directory: 1
create_directory: 0
boost::filesystem::create_directories: Invalid argument
```

The first two lines are unsurprising: `.` is a directory, and `create_directory()` is documented saying:

> Creation failure because p resolves to an existing directory shall not be treated as an error.

But the third line is a surprise to me: `create_directories(".")` failed even though `.` exists.  There is no such failure if you use a different name, like `foo` - it will happily create that directory or just return false if it exists already.

The docs have this to say:

> Effect: Establishes the postcondition by calling create_directory() for any element of p that does not exist.
>
> Postcondition: is_directory(p)

We have shown that the postcondition is true beforehand, so why does it fail?

Edit: I'm using Boost 1.63.  I see now that a commit three months ago to "Fix #12495" probably causes this problem: https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/commit/216720de55359828c2dc915b50e6ead44e00cd15 - and even includes a unit test which demands that `create_directories(".")` must fail while `create_directory(".")` must succeed, which is bizarre .

Comment: the "." directory is "special" isn't it?

Comment: I'd just report it to the developers. What do you expect from an answer here? FWIW the unit tests for `create_directory(".")` and `create_directories("..")` seem to have been reversed.

Comment: @sehe: What do you mean by "reversed" there?

Comment: @sehe: Well it surely seems to me like neither should fail, based on the documentation.

Comment: Rereading the docs, I agree. I'd just report it to the developers. What do you expect from an answer here?